# Stepwise AIC using forward selection in R

Tags: r, regression, best-fit-curve, variable-selection

I am trying to do a forward variable selection using stepwise AIC in R but I don't think that I am getting the desired results. Specifically, the function should start with no variables and keep adding variables and get their AIC values. However, when I run this I only get an AIC value for all variables. Where am I going wrong?
here is my code-

```
model.full <- lm(distance ~ ., data = FAA_unique_without_speed_air)
model.null<-lm(distance ~ 1,  data = FAA_unique_without_speed_air)
modAIC <- MASS::stepAIC(model.full,direction='forward', scope=model.full, k = 2)
```

output -

```
Start:  AIC=9161.49
distance ~ aircraft + duration + no_pasg + speed_ground + height + 
    pitch
```

Comment: could we please have a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be best to be explicit with the arguments of `stepAIC`, rather than use the defaults. Try:

1. Provide the null model as the initial model `object` when you want to do forward selection.
2. Provide *both* a lower and upper search formula in the `scope`.

For example, using the `iris` dataframe from the base library `datasets`:

```
library(MASS)

model.full <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ ., data = iris)
model.null <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ 1, data = iris)

MASS::stepAIC(model.null, direction = "forward", scope = list(lower = model.null,
                                                              upper = model.full))
```

Or if you want to use the defaults then you should be explicit about the default upper components included in the model:

```
stepAIC(model.null, direction = "forward", scope = ~ Sepal.Length + Species + Petal.Length)
```

However, as mentioned by @BenBolker you should post a reproducible example with your data so we can confirm.